# Replace title bar with a full window border

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, themes

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove the titlebar of every window and instead add a coloured border a few pixels thick around the whole window and stil keep the ability to move the window around.

I used compiz settings tool to remove window decorations but that leaves me with unmovable windows so I figured that might not be the best approach, my second idea is to edit the gtk theme. Is this possible or should i look for another window manager to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Even without window decorations, you should still be able to move the windows around, using Alt + Button1 mouse drag.

To replace them with a solid border that's equal around all sides, you'll need to create a Metacity theme which does so; or find an existing one that does already.